# postNotification expecting an OSNotification object that contains irrelevant fields

Tags: ionic2, onesignal

I am using Ionic 2 with the OneSignal native plugin.

I am trying to use the postNotification function but I can not compile my code:

```
let notificationObj = {
      contents: { en: content },
      headings: { en: title },
      include_player_ids: [playerIds],
      ios_badgeType: 'Increase',
      ios_badgeCount: 1
    };
    return this.oneSignal.postNotification(notificationObj);
```

The error tells me that my OSNotification is missing fields such as isAppInFocus, shown, etc.

But this looks like what would be expected when you handle a notificationReceived not when sending it has I cannot know in advance these values... any clue?

Comment: Not entirely related to the question, but you can also use the [One Signal Rest API](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/reference) to send notifications from your app, and it's way easier. I can add an answer explaining how to do that if you want...

Comment: Thanks @sebaferreras for your answer. I actually decided to implement everything in my backend which is a different version of OneSignal and works perfectly. But I'll keep it in mind

Comment: Yes, that's actually the best way to handle push notifications, so glad to hear that you solved the issue in that way :)